# How to display ipython widgets after calling .close() one them

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am working on a data visualisation dashboard using ipython widgets and I am trying to establish a continuous flow. My problem is that once I call `widget.close()` for some `widget`, calling `display(widget)` no longer does anything.

My plan would be start all over once the `clearOutputButton` is clicked. Does someone know what's causing this?

---

Cut down version of my code as it uses database calls:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

orgs_list = ["org_1", "org_2"]

selectOrg = widgets.Dropdown(options = orgs_list)
selectDays = widgets.IntSlider(min = 7, max = 90, value = 30, step = 1)

submitOrgButton = widgets.Button(description = 'Submit', button_style='info', tooltip = "Click here to submit")
submitUserButton = widgets.Button(description = 'Submit', button_style='info', tooltip = "Click here to submit")
submitDaysButton = widgets.Button(description = 'Submit', button_style='info', tooltip = "Click here to submit")
clearOutputButton = widgets.Button(description='New Query', button_style='info', tooltip='Make another query')



def submitOrgHandler(obj):
    print(f"Selected {selectOrg.label.upper()}")
    selectOrg.close()
    submitOrgButton.close()
    org_id = selectOrg.value
    user_emails = ["user_email_1", "user_email_2"]
    user_ids = ["user_id_1", "user_id_2"]
    user_tuples = [(email, _id) for email, _id in zip(user_emails, user_ids)]
        
    global selectUser
    selectUser = widgets.Dropdown(options = user_tuples)
    
    print("Please select a user:")
    display(selectUser)
    display(submitUserButton)

def submitUserHandler(obj):
    print(f"Selected {selectUser.label}")
    selectUser.close()
    submitUserButton.close()
    print("Please select a timespan:")
    display(selectDays)
    display(submitDaysButton)

def submitMetricHandler(obj):
    print(f"Selected timespan: {selectDays.value} days \n")
    n_days = selectDays.value
    selectDays.close()
    submitDaysButton.close()
    print(f'Displaying information in the last {selectDays.value} days for {selectUser.label}...')
    user_email = selectUser.label
    
    # Do some plotting here
    print("{Plot goes here!}")

    display(clearOutputButton)
    
def clearOutputHandler(obj):
    clear_output()

    print("Please select an organisation, a user and a timespan:")
    display(selectOrg)
    display(submitOrgButton)

print("Please select an organisation, a user and a timespan:")
display(selectOrg)
display(submitOrgButton)

submitOrgButton.on_click(submitOrgHandler)
submitUserButton.on_click(submitUserHandler)
submitDaysButton.on_click(submitMetricHandler)
clearOutputButton.on_click(clearOutputHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, one thing you could do is call the `clear_output()` function at the beginning of each event handler function instead of closing the widgets using `widget.close()`. Doing that enables you to open and close the widgets as often as you want.

The code looks like that:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

orgs_list = ["org_1", "org_2"]

selectOrg = widgets.Dropdown(options = orgs_list)
selectDays = widgets.IntSlider(min = 7, max = 90, value = 30, step = 1)

submitOrgButton = widgets.Button(description = 'Submit', button_style='info', tooltip = "Click here to submit")
submitUserButton = widgets.Button(description = 'Submit', button_style='info', tooltip = "Click here to submit")
submitDaysButton = widgets.Button(description = 'Submit', button_style='info', tooltip = "Click here to submit")
clearOutputButton = widgets.Button(description='New Query', button_style='info', tooltip='Make another query')



def submitOrgHandler(obj):
    clear_output()
    print(f"Selected {selectOrg.label.upper()}")
    org_id = selectOrg.value
    user_emails = ["user_email_1", "user_email_2"]
    user_ids = ["user_id_1", "user_id_2"]
    user_tuples = [(email, _id) for email, _id in zip(user_emails, user_ids)]
        
    global selectUser
    selectUser = widgets.Dropdown(options = user_tuples)
    
    print("Please select a user:")
    display(selectUser)
    display(submitUserButton)

def submitUserHandler(obj):
    clear_output()
    print(f"Selected {selectUser.label}")
    print("Please select a timespan:")
    display(selectDays)
    display(submitDaysButton)

def submitMetricHandler(obj):
    clear_output()
    print(f"Selected timespan: {selectDays.value} days \n")
    n_days = selectDays.value
    print(f'Displaying information in the last {selectDays.value} days for {selectUser.label}...')
    user_email = selectUser.label
    
    # Do some plotting here
    print("{Plot goes here!}")

    display(clearOutputButton)
    
def clearOutputHandler(obj):
    clear_output()

    print("Please select an organisation, a user and a timespan:")

    display(selectOrg)
    display(submitOrgButton)

print("Please select an organisation, a user and a timespan:")
display(selectOrg)
display(submitOrgButton)

submitOrgButton.on_click(submitOrgHandler)
submitUserButton.on_click(submitUserHandler)
submitDaysButton.on_click(submitMetricHandler)
clearOutputButton.on_click(clearOutputHandler)
```

Comment: I've thought of this solution too, but my aim in general is to be able to selectively close/display widgets as I want. In this case, I want the widgets to disappear after each button press, but the printed statements ("Selected {user_email}") to remain. I could just repeat the print statements after each clear_output(), but that would make the code even messier...